# vapor build command not working with Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, vapor

I am currently following the small and brief introduction to Swift Vapor by following their "Hello World" tutorial on their website. However I keep getting an error from swift-package when I try to build the project where it shows the following.

```
$ vapor build
No .build folder, fetch may take a while...
Fetching Dependencies [Failed]
Error: swift-package: error: unknown command: --enable-prefetching
```

I cannot seem to find out how to resolve this online. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: The latest version of Vapor Toolbox requires Swift 3.1+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, using swift 3.0.2, `vapor build` command doesn't work neither.
However using swift 3.1.0, `vapor build` command works well.
My Vapor toolbox version is v1.1.0

Answer (score 5):

you have not mentioned your environment, so i'm giving solution for macOS.

I had the same issue, my swift version is 3.0.2 and vapor toolbox version is 1.0.9, 
I tried the following thing to make it work

1. get into your project directory
2. create xcode project with command

   ```
   swift package generate-xcodeproj
   ```
3. open xcode project
4. Select your scheme as App like this

[image]

5. and then build and run app

hope this helps!!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you're using the correct command line tools for the Swift Version that you're using.

You can check from `Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I had Swift 3.1 installed. I deleted old version completely and installed new one and now it's building fine.

Try

```
    rm -rf /usr/local/bin/vapor
    brew tap vapor/homebrew-tap
```

than

```
brew install vapor
```

or

```
brew link vapor
```

if you have installed a new version previously.